# Adding Request Parameters to a DotNetNuke page

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm wondering if there's a simple way to specify a request parameter (i.e. CategoryID) in the page header section or somehow associated to a particular page that would be picked up by Request("CategoryID")? Or another simple approach to easily specify a Request Parameter for a DotNetNuke page that would be picked up by Request(). We need different pages to have different categoryid's.

**Detail**
We've got a module that appears on every page. It always makes a call to Request("CategoryID") to see if a category is defined for the page, if so, it filters it's results list by that category. Normally this is used when the CategoryID is specified in the URL. But in this case, we want to specify it some other way. I could probably specify a skin object as part of the skin that would look at the URL and map to the appropriate categoryID and write it out as a session variable but I'm looking for a simpler approach.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This allows you to store and retrieve CategoryID in the Page's keywords. This would be called upon page load.

```
        Dim TC As New TabController
        Dim TI As DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabInfo = TC.GetTab(TabId, PortalId, True)

        Dim tokens() As String = TI.KeyWords.Split(","c)
        For Each token As String In tokens
            Dim tokens2() As String = Trim(token).Split(":"c)
            If tokens2.Length = 2 AndAlso tokens2(0) = "CategoryID" Then
                Response.Write("My CategoryID is " & tokens2(1))
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: It seems I need to clarify my question because I don't want the same categoryid to persist between pages. Instead, for some pages, I want to be able to specify a categoryID so the module will filter by that CategoryID for that page.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but all of these options would require writing some kind of code behind and it wouldn't be easy to set the categoryID for a page through the page settings or a module's settings. Hidden fields only are stored in the ViewState if they are set as runat="server".

Comment: It is my understanding that CategoryID is not static per module -- that it changes based upon user actions, such as filtering a gridview or something. Perhaps I misunderstood? If the categoryID is always the same per instance of a module, let me know and I'll show you how to do it in the module-instance settings storage

Comment: No, categoryid needs to be set at the page level in a way that it can be picked up by the module using Request("CategoryID"). It does not have to persist between pages.

Comment: The module, Efficion's Articles module, already provides a better mechanism for doing what you've described. But that's not really what we were going for. We really want a more global solution for mapping the page to a categoryID in a way that the module can just pick it up using it's current approach. The best solution I think will eventually be to convert from our Categories to DNN's new Taxonomy/Folksonomy and have the module look to filter based on the page's tag. But we just needed a quick fix for now. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a SkinObject that handles this. Currently, I've hard coded the mapping from the TabID to the CategoryID and then I do a Response.Redirect to the page with the CategoryID appended to the URL.

I initially tried writing the CategoryID to the ViewState in the Skin Objects Page.Init but that wasn't getting picked up by the module.

I still think there is a better way (I'm worried about the SEO impact of this) but this is working for now until I come up with something better or add functionality to the module.

```
NameSpace DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Controls
Partial Class MapURLToCategoryID
    Inherits UI.Skins.SkinObjectBase

    Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        If Request("CategoryID") <> "" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim id As Int16 = -1

        Select Case Request("tabid")
            Case 92
                id = 14
            Case 93
                id = 15
            Case 227
                id = 38
            Case 95
                id = 19
            Case 91
                id = 13
            Case 226
                id = 17
            Case 94
                id = 16
            Case Else
                'do nothing

        End Select
        If id <> -1 Then
            Response.Redirect(NavigateURL("", "CategoryID=" & id.ToString), False)
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```